# Lifetime of system modeled using exponential distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I am reading [Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0538733527).

Exercise 15, Chapter 5 says:

> Consider a system consisting of three components as pictured.
>   The system will continue to function as long as the first component functions and either component 2 or component 3 functions. Let $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ denote the lifetimes of components 1, 2, and 3, respectively. Suppose the $X_i$’s are independent of one another and each $X_i$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

[image: components]

> - Let Y denote the system lifetime. Obtain the cumulative
>     distribution function of Y and differentiate to obtain the
>     pdf. [Hint: $F(y) = P(Y \leq y)$; express the event $\{Y \leq y\}$
>     in terms of unions and/or intersections of the three events
>     $\{X_1 \leq y\}$, $\{X_2 \leq y\}$, and $\{X_3 \leq y\}$.]

It is not clear to me how to build the overall cumulative distribution function. I saw [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1215796/113873) but I don't understand how to use it to fit my problem.

I tried to compute the cumulative distribution function as:

$F(y) = P(X_1 \leq y) * (P(X_2 \leq y) + P(X_3 \leq y))$

but I think it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$Y = X_1\wedge(X_2\vee X_3)$$ and for $y\geqslant 0$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_2\vee X_3\leqslant y) &= \mathbb P(X_2\leqslant y, X_3\leqslant y)\\
&= \mathbb P(X_2\leqslant y)\mathbb P(X_3\leqslant y)\\
&= (1-e^{-\lambda y})^2.
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_1\wedge(X_2\vee X_3)>y) &= \mathbb P(X_1>y, X_2\vee X_3>y)\\
&= \mathbb P(X_1>y)\mathbb P(X_2\vee X_3 >y)\\
&= e^{-\lambda y}\left(1-\left(1-e^{-\lambda y}\right)^2\right),
\end{align}
and so the CDF of $Y$ is
$$F_Y(y) = 1 - e^{-\lambda y}\left(1-\left(1-e^{-\lambda y}\right)^2\right),\ y\geqslant 0. $$

Comment: You should probably clarify that $\wedge$ means "min" and $\vee$ means "max". This is actually pretty standard notation, but a beginner is still not likely to be familiar with it.

Comment: Nice answer. However, it is not clear to me why in the second part (Probability of $X_2 \lor X_3 \leq y$) you multiplied the two probabilities. Shouldn't the joint probability be less than the individual probabilities since they are less than 1?

Comment: That equality follows from independence.

Comment: The equality that you are referring to follows when you are taking the intersection of two events. In the case above, in determining the probability of union of two events, you used the probability of intersection of $X_2$ and $X_3$. @Math1000